# Cross classes functions and scope in javascript error with phaserJS

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I have a game state that adds a new object and calls a function on it.

```
BasicGame.Game.prototype = {
    create: function () { 
        var levelController = new LevelController(this, playerType);
        var playerType = 3;
        levelController.makePlayer(playerType);
    },
    createPlayer: function (playerType) { 
        console.log('Player ' + playerType + ' created');
    }
}
```

I want to access a function from game state.

```
var LevelController = function (superThis) {};
LevelController.prototype = {}
LevelController.prototype.makePlayer= function(superThis, playerType){  
    superThis.createPlayer(superThis, playerType){ 
}
```

Uncaught TypeError: ******** is not a function at InitFish

Comment: Is something missing? What is `InitFish`? And what is "********"?

Comment: sorry the error was from project and not from example... i think i need to scope it with this.game.function

Comment: So is your question answered / moot now?